# What is this Google Settings app that installed itself on my phone?

Tags: security, google-account, google-settings

Today, all of a sudden I saw this app in my *Samsung Galaxy Y* mobile phone:
[image: screenshot with google settings]

I am talking about the app named `"Google Settings"`

I uninstalled it immediately only to find it installed again a few hours later.

My mobile phone is rooted and I did have access to internet through the phone during this period?

Can anyone tell me as to what is going on? Should I worry? What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Google settings app is being put their either by the Maps app, Search app, or the Google+ app.

It's a unified settings/sign-in thing they just added in literally yesterday and allows you to manage the settings for all of the above (and probably more in future) from one menu.

http://www.engadget.com/2013/02/27/google-settings-app-sneaks-onto-android-to-bolster-g-sign-in/

Comment: +1 I just noticed this yesterday as well and wondered how it got there.

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the Google Play Services app. You cannot remove it unless you remove Play Services. It gives you settings for Google apps, like Maps, Games, Device Manager etc.

Answer (score -2):

I unistalled google play services and that removed it from the phone. Not sure what else will be affected but I am still able to download/install apps from play store. I figure I may miss the next version of play store that comes out. Better than them sneaking stuff in

Comment: It's almost guaranteed that pretty much stuff will break. Play services is Google's software shim to roll out API updates for all devices (2.2-4.x) even if the manufacturer doesn't offer update anymore. Many apps depend on it, read more on play services here: http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/09/balky-carriers-and-slow-oems-step-aside-google-is-defragging-android/